# Rajawali camera rotation

Tags: android, rajawali

I've just started looking at Rajawali and seem to have a misunderstanding of some of the principles.

For example, I have my planet earth sitting at (0,0,0) and I can rotate the camera around it using `getCurrentCamera().setRotY(getCurrentCamera().getRotY() + 1)` in onDraw(). This works okay.

However, if I also do a `getCurrentCamera().getPosition()` in onDraw() this never changes.

So I suppose my question is how can both these be true? Hopefully someone can explain it to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A camera has 3 properties defining it's location and orientation in 3D space:
- Position (X, Y, Z)
- Rotation (Angle in X, Y, Z axis)
- Up (a point "above" position x, y, z)

You can use getCurrentCamera().setPosition(new Vector(100.0, 0.0, 0.0)) to move the camera.